# In which areas of Artificial Intelligence are probability theory and logic used?

Tags: logic, artificial-intelligence, probability, probability-theory

I did a course in AI and I was surprised how probability theory and logic were used to inference knowledge. So I want to do more courses in artificial intelligence where I can continue using probability and logic. Do you know some of them? For example, machine learning, modal logic, mathematical logic,...
Thanks :)

Comment: Machine learning these days is mostly based on Bayesian probability and decision theory, so maybe that's of interest to you. My advice is to look over the conference proceedings of NIPS (Neural Information Processing Systems conference) and UAI (Uncertainty in Artificial Intelligence conference) and see if there are some topics that interest you.

Comment: If you are interested in machine learning, then [Cross Validated](http://www.stats.stackexchange.com) sounds like the perfect place for you.

Comment: Basically all of them.  Bayesian probability is the more modern approach.

Answer (score 1):

Logic and probabilistic inference are two main lines of AI that are still widely separated. Integrating the two is an active field of research (see for example [Markov Logic Networks](http://homes.cs.washington.edu/~pedrod/papers/mlj05.pdf), or [ProbLog](https://dtai.cs.kuleuven.be/problog/)).

That research however assumes you already know both logic and probabilistic inference. If you are starting to learn, you may want to focus on one of the two. Probabilistic inference is much more prevalent and used in practice these days, for example for machine learning. A [course in graphical models](https://www.coursera.org/course/pgm) would be a good start. There are also [specific classes in applying all that to natural language processing (NLP)](https://www.coursera.org/course/nlp), which is one of the most common applications.

If you prefer to learn more about logic, then there are theoretical [classes](https://www.coursera.org/course/intrologic) on that. [Prolog](http://www.learnprolognow.org/) can also be interesting.